# Get only declared methods of a class (excluding inherited classes' methods)

Tags: python, inheritance

I got a problem in Python 3.5. I have a class (B) which inherits from another one (A). I'm trying get only declared methods in B but it returns the declared methods in class B and also inherited methods from class A.

Here the code:

```
class A:

    def a_method_1(self):
        """ WILL BE OVERRIDEN """
        return True

    def a_method_2(self):
        """ WON'T BE OVERRIDEN """
        return True


class B(A):

    def b_method_1(self):
        """ NOT OVERRIDEN """
        return True

    def get_methods(self):
        """ 
           NOT OVERRIDEN 
           This function filters special python methods. 
        """

        methods = [method for method in dir(self) if callable(getattr(self, method))
                      and not method[:2] == '__']
        return methods

    def a_method_1(self):
        """ OVERRIDEN """
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    B_obj = B()
    print(B_obj.get_methods())
```

Returns :

```
>>> ['a_method_1', 'a_method_2', 'b_method_1', 'get_methods']
```

And I would want :

```
>>> ['a_method_1', 'b_method_1', 'get_methods']
```

**How can I modify get_methods to filter inherited methods?**

Have a good day,
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to just filter the list comphrension, or do you want to remove any undesired inherited methods from the class completely?

Comment: @Reti43 I would want to filter the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [vars](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> vars(B)
mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'a_method_1': <function __main__.B.a_method_1>,
              'b_method_1': <function __main__.B.b_method_1>,
              'get_methods': <function __main__.B.get_methods>})


>>> import inspect
>>> [name for name, attr in vars(B).items() if inspect.isfunction(attr)]
['b_method_1', 'get_methods', 'a_method_1']
```

Comment: If you want to the same from a class instance, `vars(B_obj.__class__)` will achieve the same. Or `self.__class__` if you're doing it within the instance itself.

Comment: Right, although I would suggest using `type(B_obj)` over `B_obj.__class__` in python3 and new-style classes in Python2.